# What's that weird food called that they eat in Dover Delaware?

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, us-citizens, local-cuisine, delaware

I stayed in Dover Delaware years ago and was introduced to a breakfast food that the locals raved about. I forget what it's called and I can't for the life of me find the name of it. It's comparable to **scrapple**, but it's *not* scrapple. I have vivid memories from when I visited of people there saying they hated scrapple, but they loved this other mystery-meaty stuff.

Anyone know what I'm talking about? I remember people saying the best way to cook it was to cut it thin and cook it like bacon.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47019/discussion-on-question-by-shemseger-whats-that-weird-food-called-that-they-eat).

Comment: Do any of the "See also" on wikipedia ring a bell?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrapple#See_also

Answer (score 4):

Since it wasn't scrapple, it may have been Spam, sliced and fried.

For the uninitiated, scrapple is made of pig parts, corn meal, and spices, not unlike sausage, and has been produced in the mid-Atlantic region of the United States since the early days of the colonies.

Similarly, Spam is the brand of a canned product, made of cooked meats (pork, ham, whatever else). As scrapple is the iconic food product of Delaware, Spam is that of Hawaii, so popular that it's sometimes referred to as 'The Hawaiian Steak.'

Spam has been around since the 1930's, and became so ubiquitous that it inspired the Monty Python sketch as tasting horrible, inescapable and led to the name being used for junk, unsolicited email.

Comment: It wasn't spam, someone already posted that as an answer but it got deleted. Spam is a Minnesota thing.

Comment: Then @ShemSeger perhaps it's time to close this discussion as off topic :-)

Comment: Must...resist...flagging...this...answer...as...spam....

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g34059-d114447-r269108795-Hotel_du_Pont-Wilmington_Delaware.html#UR269108795) tripadvisor review of the [Hotel du Pont](http://www.hoteldupont.com/) refers to a room service breakfast "of cream chipped beef with scrapple" (which) "is not to be missed".

I don't see the room service menu, but the their [Green Room](http://www.hoteldupont.com/dining-en.html) restaurant only shows creamed beef on the breakfast menu.

[image]

Looks like a fancy place. I'd be tempted to use the military term for this dish [shit-on-a-shingle](http://www.cooksinfo.com/shit-on-a-shingle-recipe).

Comment: No, not creamed chipped beef. It was a kind of scrapple, but they didn't call it scrapple.

Answer (score 1):

Speculative, since I've only ever been to Delaware twice and never breakfasted out there, but googling suggests (via http://www.onlyinyourstate.com/delaware/iconic-delaware-foods/ ) **Cream Chipped Beef**, which is "Dried beef in white sauce, poured over toast usually". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipped_beef) asserts (my emphases)

> Chipped beef is served in many diners and restaurants in the United
>   States as a breakfast item. **Creamed** chipped beef is standard fare
>   on many such diner menus, **especially in the Mid-Atlantic**, but has
>   become harder to find in chain restaurants that serve breakfast

Comment: Eh, creamed chipped beef is nothing like scrapple. But, I'll take it over scrapple any day!

Answer (score 0):

Head cheese or better known as souse! Only thing people confuse scrapple for!

[Link to a wikipedia page about head cheese.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_cheese)

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Not heard about it for years but Laura Ingals Wilder wrote about it in her books, so it has been around for a long time.

Answer (score -1):

It could be [Canadian bacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_bacon#Canadian_bacon), but I'm gonna guess it was [pork roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pork_roll).

Comment: Perphaps it was Spam, since OP says it wasn't scrapple. Spam has nothing to do with Delaware (as scrapple does), but has everything to do with Hawaii.

Comment: @Dorothy: I can see how Spam might be compared to scrapple. Post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm Canadian, for the record, only Americans call it "Canadian bacon" In Canada, it's just called "back bacon". Same goes for white cheddar, I had no idea what "American Cheese" was when I first visited the states, the lady at Subway just looked at me like I was retarded when I told her I wanted white cheddar on my sub.

Comment: We have white cheddar. It's just not a kind of cheese you can (AFAIK) get in Subway. I don't know if American cheese is technically a cheddar, but it's sure not white, so I'd be surprised if you called it white cheddar in Canada.

Comment: Both of those things are common across the US, not specific to DE.

Comment: @davidvc American cheese can be white.  Originally it was only white.

Comment: Note that white cheddar and American cheese (of whatever color) are VERY VERY VERY different things.